# Why does rollup.js not include - exclusively - exported values in its output?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, rollupjs, es6-modules

I am new to Rollup - rollupjs.org - and don't understand why exported values are being removed; presumably by treeshaking during the rollup.

I have a `data.json` with some basic data that I will want to provide as part of a module:

```
{
    "colors": ["red", "green", "blue"],
    "shapes": ["circle", "triangle", "square"]
}
```

... and a module that will be exporting them:

```
import { colors, shapes } from './data.json';

function run() {
  console.log('Run, Forest, Run.');
}

export default run;

export {
  colors,
  shapes
};
```

Does rollup.js not recognize export statements as considered "use" so anything that is exclusively in there will get "treeshaken" out of the output?

Comment: Please show us how you are importing that module, how you invoke Rollup on your application, and what the result looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *entry module* exports `colors` and `shapes`, that's considered 'using' those values. If some internal module exports them, they'll only be included if another module imports `colors` or `shapes` and uses them.

Here's a [demonstration of the first case](http://rollupjs.org/repl/?shareable=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) (entry module exports the values), and here's a [demonstration of the second case](http://rollupjs.org/repl/?shareable=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) (the values are exported by `not-main.js`).

If that's not what's happening in your case, it's possible you've encountered a bug, in which case please [file an issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues)!

Comment: Thank you for the response. You are correct, rollup.js is performing as it should; I think that I was getting lost in my layers of abstraction - too much indirection - to see that I was exporting the correct "things" but at the wrong level. Once I moved the export to the correct place things are working properly now.